# Do we conclude from these relations that $ny-hx \mid x(nx-h)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We have the following relations $$p^i \mid ny-hx \\ (ny-hx)q=(nx-h)n^f \\ p^i \mid x(nx-h)$$ where $p$ is a prime, $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n>1$, $|h|<n$, $hx\geq 0$, $i>0$.

Do we conclude from these relations the following? $$ny-hx \mid x(nx-h)$$

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I am looking at the following proof:

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

$$$$

At the part "By the Chinese Remainder Theorem ... $ny-hx \mid x(nx-h)$."

I haven't understood how from the relations $(7)$ and $(5)$ we conclude that $ny-hx \mid x(nx-h)$.

Could you explain it to me?

Comment: $i$ is constant?

Comment: It stands that $i>0$. I added it at my initial post above... What does it stand in that case? @Elaqqad

Comment: I added the proof that I am looking at to my initial post. At the part "By the Chinese Remainder Theorem ... $ny-hx \mid x(nx-h)$." 

I haven't understood how from the relations $(7)$ and $(5)$ we conclude that $ny-hx \mid x(nx-h)$. 

Could you explain it to me? @Elaqqad

Comment: What deos the $|_n$ symbol means ?

Comment: $$K \mid_n M \leftrightarrow \exists q, f \in \mathbb{Z} : M=Kqn^{-f}$$ @Elaqqad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the part of the proof you don't understand is (correct me if I'm wrong).

1. We can prove easily that, by the Chinese remainder theorem there exists an $h\mod n$ such that $h=h(p) \mod p$ for every prime $p$ dividing $n$. (this one is clear ?)
2. $(7)$  For every prime $p$, if $h=h(p) \mod p$ then $$ p^i| ny-hx \implies p^i|x$$
3. $(5)$ For all $k$ such that $|k|<n$ we have :
   $$ny-kx|_n nx-k $$

> **Question :** How can we deduce from $1.,2.$ and $3.$ that $ny-hx|x(nx-h)$ ?

**1. Sketch or hint**
As we can see, from $1.$ we can apply $2.$ for every prime $p$ which divides $n$ hence we would say that "the commune part between $n$ and $ny-hx$ must divide $x$" and from $3$ we can deduce that "the other part of $ny-hx$ must divide $nx-h$". These two observations both implies that $ny-hx$ divides $x(nx-h)$

**2. Solution :**  In order to justify $1$, let $n=q_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots q_k^{\alpha_k}$ the factorization of $n$. let $a_i=0$ if $ny$ and $x$ are divisible by the same powers of $q_i$ and $a_i=1$ otherwise, this means that $a_i=h(q_i)$ for every $i=1,\dots,k$. the Chinese remainder theorem implies that there exist an $h<n$ such that:
$$\begin{align}h&\equiv a_1\mod q_1\\ h &\equiv a_2 \mod q_2 \\  h &\equiv \cdots \mod \cdots \\h &\equiv a_k\mod q_k\end{align} $$.

Now we can write :
$$ny-hx =q_1^{r_1}\cdots q_k^{r_k} a \quad \gcd(a,n)=1\tag {*}$$
for every $i=1,cdot,k$ we have $h=h(p_i)\mod p_i$ so we can apply $2$: because $q_i^{r_i}$ divides $ny-hx$ hence $q_i^{r_i}$ divides $x$ this is true for every $i=1,cdot,k$ then :
$$q_1^{r_1}\cdots q_k^{r_k}|x \tag{**}$$

But we have also $h<n$ so we can apply $3.$ hence **there exists** $f,q$ such that
$$(ny-hx)q=(nx-h)n^f $$
but $a|ny-hx$ hence $a|(nx-h)n^f$ and because $\gcd(a,n^f)=1$ we can deduce (using Euclid's lemma) that $a|nx-h \tag {***}$
Finally from ($*$),($**$) and ($***$) we can deduce the result.

**Observation :** In the beginning you wrote the problem without quantifiers and conditions which gives another sense to the assertions so every time you copy a problem you have to understand the relevant parts of implications and the result you may for example write:

Let $h,n,x,y$ be some integers such that :
$$\begin{align}\exists f,q \quad (ny-hx)q=(nx-h)n^f \\
  \forall i>0 \quad p^i| ny-hx \implies p^i|x\end{align}$$
for every prime $p$ dividing $n$ (which is equivalent to $h=h(p)\mod p$ because of the definition of $h$)

If you have written the problem this way there would not be such a misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanantion!! :-) $$$$ After this part, there is the following: "From $|h|<n$ and $x \neq 0$ follows $x(nx-h)>0$" Why does this follows?

Comment: Is it as folllows? $|h|<n \Rightarrow -n<-h<n$. $$$$ -If $x>0$ then $nx>0$. Then $nx-x<nx-h<nx+n \Rightarrow 0\leq n(x-1)<nx-h<n(x+1)$. Since $nx-h>0$ and $x>0$, we conclude that $x(nx-h)>0$. $$$$ -If $x<0$ then $nx<0$. Then $nx-x<nx-h<nx+n \Rightarrow  n(x-1)<nx-h<n(x+1)\leq 0$. Since $nx-h<0$ and $x<0$, we conclude that $x(nx-h)<0$.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right!! We have that $$|ny-hx|\leq |x(nx-h)|=x(nx-h)=nx^2-hx$$ How do we expand the left side to get the inequality : $n|y|-|hx| \leq nx^2-hx$ ? Does it stand that $$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$$ ?

Comment: we have $\left||a|-|b| \right| \leq |a-b|$, but $\left|n|y|-|hx|\right|=n|y|-|hx|$ because $ |hx|<n|y|$, the proof is not very easy you have to think deeply to understand it completely. You may also try to prove the lemma independently in order to understand all the problems and the features the proof have to solve

Comment: I see... At the end of the proof how do we get $2nx+1 \mid -2$ from $2nx+1 \mid -4n^2x^2-1$ ?

Comment: because we have already $2nx+1|4n^2x^2-1 $ from the fact $a+b|a^2-b^2$ hence $2nx+1| (4n^2x^2-1)+(−4n^2x^2−1)=-2$

Comment: I understand!! $$$$ Is the direction $\Rightarrow$ of the proof, that is said obvious, as follows? $$$$ Let $y=x^2$. Then $4n^2y-1=4n^2x^2-1=(2nx-1)(2nx+1)$. 

So $2nx-1 \mid 4n^2y-1$ and $2nx+1 \mid 4n^2y-1$. 

Since $(2nx \pm 1, n)=1$ we have that $2nx-1 \mid_n 4n^2y-1$ and $2nx+1 \mid_n 4n^2y-1$. (that follows from a remark) 

We have also that $ny-kx=nx^2-kx=x(nx-k)$. 

From the relation $x \mid_n 1$ we have that $xq=n^f$. 

So $$q(ny-kx)=xq(nx-k) \Rightarrow q(ny-kx)=n^f(nx-k) \Rightarrow nx-k=q(ny-kx)n^{-f} \\ \Rightarrow ny-kx \mid_n nx-k.$$

Comment: yes that's correct also

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Now I saw that you have edited one your comments... You say that $|n|y|-|hx||=n|y|-|hx|$ because $|hx|<n|y|$. But why does the inequality $|hx|<n|y|$ stand?

Comment: combine the two relations $(6)$ and $h<n$, remeber that $x\leq x^2\leq |y|$